'ssh -X' between Ubuntu 22.04.4 - DISPLAY not set
I can't actually get X sessions forwarded.  /etc/ssh/sshd_config does have
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
ssh does seem to be working:
debug1: Remote: /home/joliver/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/joliver/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.

but DISPLAY is still localhost:10.0
What do I need to do to get X forwarded?

If this is Ubuntu Server or Desktop this is not a valid version number. Please edit and correct.

Please edit your question and add the exact version of Ubuntu you are using. Are you using Ubuntu Core for IoT? Only Ubuntu Core has two number versions. Desktop and servers have version numbers in the YY.MM format.  Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10? Is this a desktop or server version of Ubuntu? Is it using Wayland or Xorg?

So this is weird... when I connect, firefox and another application that I care about are launched on the remote host, but xclock is launched on the local host!

The issue may be that firefox (and the other application) are packaged as snaps - see for example X11 Forwarding using SSH

I just removed the snap of firefox and installed it as an actual package.  The other app I care about right now is a pip install thing.

That snapcraft link led me to realize that my $XAUTHORITY was set to /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.5NH7S2.  However, fixing that didn't help.

I also tried:
ln -s -f "$XAUTHORITY" ~/.Xauthority
